# How to remove a disk using PowerShell

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I've inserted a removable disk to one of the physical servers, then I ejected it, but it is still appears, as shown below:

[image]

I've restarted the server multiple times, but it did not work. Is there any workaround to remove it using PowerShell?

Comment: Is it a disk, optical, or usb drive? Is it still physically connected to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Can you rescan the storage in Disk Management and show the diskpart output (for volumes and disks). Also, check this article might be helpful :

[Dismount USB External Drive using powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/130887/dismount-usb-external-drive-using-powershell)